# RecordPageClick parameters

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, display-template

I need to change the search criteria paramater that is passed onto RecordPageClick method vis JavaScript

I am hoping to do this in the display template or the search page template

What is the best way to manipulate the parameters passed on to the [RecordPageClick](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/office/jj916814(v=office.15)) method or call RecordPageClick from a display template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Add a method in your page template or master page as appropriate for you. This method is from Search.clientcontrols.js located in the [layouts folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/dn768292(v%3Doffice.15))

```
function recordClick(c) {
    var a = "Result";
    var d = Srch.U.getClientComponent(c);
    if (!Srch.U.n(d) && Srch.DisplayControl.isInstanceOfType(d)) {
        var e = d
            , f = e.get_dataProvider();
        if (!Srch.U.n(f)) {
            var b = {};
            g = Srch.U.getTableProperty(e.$B_3, "piPageImpression");
            if (!Srch.U.e(g)) {
                b["piPageImpression"] = g;
            }
            if (Srch.U.e(piPageImpression)) {
                return;
            }
            b["piPageImpression"] = piPageImpression;
            var h = Srch.U.getTableProperty(e.$B_3, "SourceId");
            if (!Srch.U.n(h))
                b["SourceId"] = h;
            b["piClickType"] = a;
            var i = Srch.U.findResultObjectFromDOM(c, "Group");
            if (!Srch.U.n(i)) {
                var j = Srch.U.getTableProperty(i, "piPageImpressionBlockType");
                if (!Srch.U.n(j))
                    b["piPageImpressionBlockType"] = j;
            }
            if (a === "Result" || a === "DeepLink" || a === "Hover" || a === "HoverWithWAC" || a === "HoverSection" || a === "ActionFollow" || a === "ActionViewLibrary" || a === "ActionEdit" || a === "ActionSend" || a === "ActionViewDupes") {
                var k = Srch.U.findResultObjectFromDOM(c, "Item");
                if (!Srch.U.n(k)) {
                    b["piSearchResult"] = k;
                    if (a === "DeepLink")
                        if (!Srch.U.n(c) && c.nodeType === 1) {
                            var l = c.getAttribute("linkIndex");
                            if (!Srch.U.n(l))
                                b["piSearchSubResultIndex"] = parseInt(l) + 1;
                        }
                }
            }

            b["piUserQuery"] = c.getAttribute("searchterm");
            Srch.ClickRecorder.recordPageClick(b);
        }
    }
}
```

> 2. In the display template, handle the click as follows

```
var titleHtml = String.format('<a clicktype="{0}" id="{1}" href="{2}" class="ms-srch-item-link" title="{3}" onfocus="{4}" target="{5}" {6} searchterm="{7}" onclick="recordClick(this);">{8}</a>',
$htmlEncode(clickType), $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.titleLink), $urlHtmlEncodeString(url), $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title),
showHoverPanelCallback, targetWindow, appAttribs, $htmlEncode(searchQueryText), itemModifiedTitle);
```